# get the index of deleted row

Tags: r, indexing, delete-row

I have to delete a row in a dataframe and get the index of the deleted row.

In practice I click on a row of a table in a shiny app and delete it with an action button:

From this row I need the index:

Here is an example to demonstrate what I would like to do:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- diamonds %>% 
  select(1:2) %>% 
  slice(1:5)

  carat cut    
  <dbl> <ord>  
1  0.23 Ideal  
2  0.21 Premium
3  0.23 Good   
4  0.29 Premium
5  0.31 Good
```

From df1 I delete `row 3` and get `df2`. But I need the index of the deleted row as vector.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  slice(-3)

  carat cut    
  <dbl> <ord>  
1  0.23 Ideal  
2  0.21 Premium
3  0.29 Premium
4  0.31 Good
```

I have tried:

```
anti_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  pull(id)
```

which gives:

```
[1] "1"
```

Expected Output

```
[1] "3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a sequence column in 'df1'

```
df1 <- diamonds %>% 
       select(1:2) %>% 
       slice(1:5) %>%
       mutate(rn = row_number())
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  slice(-3)
```

and then just `pull` the `rn`

```
anti_join(df1, df2) %>% 
    pull('rn')
#[1] 3
```

---

`rownames_to_column` doesn't give the correct row number because `tibble` doesn't allow for row names and it resets the row number on each subset, thus we get only the changed row number instead of the original one.  In addition to the `tibble` case, here the `slice` does reset i.e. if we check the functions involved in it, there is a call to `dplyr_new_data_frame`, which may be resetting the row number

```
> methods("slice")
#[1] slice.data.frame* slice.index    
> getAnywhere("slice.data.frame")
function (.data, ..., .preserve = FALSE) 
{
    loc <- slice_rows(.data, ...)
    dplyr_row_slice(.data, loc, preserve = .preserve)
}
> dplyr:: dplyr_row_slice
function (data, i, ...) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(i) && !is.logical(i)) {
        abort("`i` must be an numeric or logical vector.")
    }
    UseMethod("dplyr_row_slice")
}
> methods("dplyr_row_slice")
[1] dplyr_row_slice.data.frame* dplyr_row_slice.grouped_df* dplyr_row_slice.rowwise_df*

> getAnywhere("dplyr_row_slice.data.frame")
function (data, i, ...) 
{
    dplyr_reconstruct(vec_slice(data, i), data)
}
> dplyr_reconstruct
function (data, template) 
{
    data <- dplyr_new_data_frame(data)
    return(dplyr_reconstruct_dispatch(data, template))
    UseMethod("dplyr_reconstruct", template)
}
> dplyr:::dplyr_new_data_frame
function (x = data.frame(), n = NULL, ..., row.names = NULL, 
    class = NULL) 
{
    row.names <- row.names %||% .row_names_info(x, type = 0L)
    new_data_frame(x, n = n, ..., row.names = row.names, class = class)
}
```

Comment: By the way this index issue with rownames and tibbles was the reason for this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626205/deleting-always-the-first-row-in-a-shiny-crud-app-only-after-adding-preexsitent>